# Python: adding multiple products and prices to a shopping cart

Tags: python, dictionary

I am completing the Python course on CodeAcademy (I am running the code on my computer not CodeAcademy) and wrote this piece of code to add items to a shopping cart. The shopping cart is a dictionary.

```
class ShoppingCart(object):

    """Creates shopping cart objects
    for users of our fine website."""

    items_in_cart = {}

    def __init__(self, customer_name):
        self.customer_name = customer_name

    def add_item(self, product, price):
        """Add product to the cart."""
        if not product in self.items_in_cart:
            self.items_in_cart[product] = price
            print product + " added."
        else:
            print product + " is already in the cart."

my_cart = ShoppingCart("Amy")

my_cart.add_item("Nishiki Modulus", "$400")

print my_cart.items_in_cart
```

This code works and returns:

```
Nishiki Modulus added.
{'Nishiki Modulus': '$400'}
```

But I would like to figure out how to add several items (and prices) at the same time. I have been experimenting with no luck.

I ran

```
class ShoppingCart(object):

    items_in_cart = {}
    def __init__(self, customer_name):
        self.customer_name = customer_name

    def add_item(self, product, price):
        """Add product to the cart."""
        for products in product:
            if not products in self.items_in_cart:
                self.items_in_cart[products] = price
                print "added."
            else:
                print "Product is already in the cart."

my_cart = ShoppingCart("Amy")

my_cart.add_item(["Nishiki Modulus", "Trek 700", "Fuji Sportif"], ["$400", "$450", "$700"])

print my_cart.items_in_cart
```

As I predicted, the keys are right but not the values. This returns:

```
added.
added.
added.
{'Trek 700': ['$400', '$450', '$700'], 'Fuji Sportif': ['$400', '$450', '$700'],     'Nishiki Modulus': ['$400', '$450', '$700']}
```

I'm think something along the lines of:

```
for products, price in product.items():
```

but then I can't figure out how to correctly add the list to items_in_cart

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Try to write code that is clear and meaningful.  This will help you and others understand what's going on, and what the intention of your code is.  For example, `for products in product` is nonsensical: `products` is each single item and `product` is multiple items.

Comment: Thanks John, I do understand what you are saying. I missed-matched the plural forms and this can be confusing. I will work on writing my code in better form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `zip` the products and their prices like this

```
for prod, money in zip(product, price):
    if not prod in self.items_in_cart:
        self.items_in_cart[prod] = money
        print "added."
    else:
        print "Product is already in the cart."
```

This will zip the `product` and `price` list and give one value at a time from both the lists. So we will get the product and its corresponding price.

Or you can iterate the `product` list, and get the corresponding value from the `price` with the index, like this

```
for index, prod in enumerate(product):
    if not prod in self.items_in_cart:
        self.items_in_cart[prod] = price[index]
        print "added."
    else:
        print "Product is already in the cart."
```

Comment: Thanks! I have not encountered the zip function yet (very knew to Python and programming in general) but after looking it up this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with simple-indexed `for` loop:

```
def add_item(self, product, price):
    """Add product to the cart."""
    for index in range(len(product):
        if not product[index] in self.items_in_cart:
            self.items_in_cart[product[index]] = price[index]
            print "added."
        else:
            print "Product is already in the cart."
```

Or use `zip`:

```
for products, prices in zip(product, price):
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value of items_in_cart[product] to price, a list of strings. You should be setting it to one of the strings in price.

Here's the ShoppingCart class fixed:

```
class ShoppingCart(object):

    items_in_cart = {}
    def __init__(self, customer_name):
        self.customer_name = customer_name

    def add_item(self, product, price):
        """Add product to the cart."""
        priceIndex = 0
        for products in product:
            if not products in self.items_in_cart:
                self.items_in_cart[products] = price[priceIndex]
                print "added."

            else:
                print "Product is already in the cart."

            priceIndex += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new method `add_items` that calls your original `add_item` in a loop. This will keep your code cleaner and easier to work with.

```
class ShoppingCart(object):

    items_in_cart = {}
    def __init__(self, customer_name):
        self.customer_name = customer_name

    def add_item(self, product, price):
        """Add product to the cart."""
        if not product in self.items_in_cart:
            self.items_in_cart[product] = price
            print product + " added."
        else:
            print product + " is already in the cart."

    def add_items(self, products, prices):
        for product, price in zip(products, prices):
            self.add_item(product, price)

my_cart = ShoppingCart("Amy")

my_cart.add_items(["Nishiki Modulus", "Trek 700", "Fuji Sportif"], ["$400", "$450", "$700"])
print my_cart.items_in_cart
```